# Splitting field over Z_2

Tags: finite-fields, splitting-field

Let $$f(x)=(x^3+x+1)(x^2+x+1)$$ and E is splitting field over $Z_2$

And how can i get $[E:Z_2]$ ?

I used to find the the splitting field of $(x^3+x+1)$ of $f(x)$ over $GF(2)$ is $GF(2^3)$ but i don't know this condition.

Please help.

Comment: The other degree is $2$ and they are relatively prime.

Comment: @tokentoucan then, how can i get the result? Please the process.

Comment: You have two extensions of the same field, and their degrees are relatively prime. Do you know the Tower Law? You can use it to get the degree of the splitting field.

Comment: Making any progress, Chanr?